# Get the row value when the button inside the particular row is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, html, dom

I have a datatable where I add a new row when a button is clicked. In that row I have a button , by clicking that I need to get the clicked row values.
i have tried with this code, where it dosen't fire.

```
$(".add-beneficiary").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("Button Clicked");
});
```

This code is to add the textbox in the table when clicking the add row (this works perfect)

```
$('#addRow').on('click', function () {
    debugger;  
    ctr++;
    var _beneficiaryname = "_beneficiaryname" + ctr;
    var _beneficiarytype = "_beneficiarytype" + ctr;
    var _beneficiarypercent = "_beneficiarypercent" + ctr;
    var _addbtn = "_addbtn" + ctr;
    var newTr = '<tr><td><input type="text" class="nr" id=' + _beneficiaryname + ' /></td><td><select class="form-control relationshiptype"  id=' + _beneficiarytype + '>' + selectoption + '</select> </td><td><input type="text" id=' + _beneficiarypercent + ' /></td><td> <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary add-beneficiary" id=' + _addbtn + ' >Add Beneficiary</button></td></tr>';
     //<td><div class=ibox-tools><a class=dropdown-toggle data-toggle=dropdown href=#><i class=fa fa-wrench></i></a><ul class=dropdown-menu dropdown-user><li><a href=# onclick=AddBeneficiaryFunction()>Add</a></li></ul></div></td>
     $('#jsontable').append(newTr);
 });
```

I don't know how to get the row value?

Comment: which value? the input from the select? Can you post a sample of the HTML from the table and identify the information that you want?

Comment: @jorjordandan: i need the particular <tr> values.

Comment: Do you mean the values of the textbox and select in the row? And when do you need them (in response to the `$(".add-beneficiary").click()` function)?

Comment: @StephenMuecke: exactly.!!

Comment: You will need to use event delegation. But what is the point of giving your elements an `id` attribute in this case?

Comment: @StephenMuecke: I have just added to identify whether the row textbox and select have different id's when clicking the addrow button. I just need to get the row value, that is my need..

Comment: Remove the `id` attributes - they are not necessary. Use event delegation (`.on()`) and relative selectors. See answer by metamorph_online

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you just need html of the tr of the button that was clicked try the following:

```
$('#jsontable').on('click', '.btn', function()
{
    alert($(this).closest('tr').html());

});
```

if you need value of the input clicked:

```
$('#jsontable').on('click', '.btn', function()
{
    alert($(this).closest('tr').find('.nr').val());

});
```

I hope you got the idea? For generated buttons you need specify additionally button identifier on click action, and selector must be "stable(not generated)" DOM element. Like already people said it is called event delegation.

http://jsfiddle.net/mhsxchf7/ - demo

Comment: I got the 1st <td> of the table by ur 2nd option. What should be modified if I want the whole <td> values of the particular <tr>??

Comment: I'm afraid you need to assign input values to variables and then you may do with those variables whatever you want.

Comment: Is it not necessary to use the fnGetPosition() and fnGetData() to obtain the <tr> position and to get the data in the <tr>.?

Comment: @AarthiRavendiran, absolutely not. `var textBoxValue = $(this).closest('tr').find('input').val();` and `var selectValue = $(this).closest('tr').find('select').val();` will give you the 2 values of the form controls

Comment: @StephenMuecke: If I have more inputs and select in a <tr> does the find() works?

Comment: Of course -`$(this).closest('tr').find('input').last().val();` will get the last one for example - or `$(this).closest('tr').find('input').eq(2)().val();` will get the 3rd one (assuming you have at least 3)

Comment: And i have [updated the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mhsxchf7/1/) to show how you should be adding the new row - not sure how even you can understand your code, let alone anyone else :)

Comment: @StephenMuecke: I got the idea.. Thank u for clarifying my doubts with patience and nw I let it go..:)